# String Permutation

Tags: c++, string

I'm struggling to work out what I am doing wrong with my current project. Firstly, my aim is to try and program a bruteforce attack using all the letters in the alphabet and numbers from 0-9.

I stumbled on string permutation which allows me to generate all combinations possible from characters in a string. e.g `abc` would give me `abc`, `acb`, `bca`.. etc. I have a problem though as it displays a line of 36 characters. I want it to generate all combinations from 2 character/number long combinations such as `aa` `a1` `a2` all the way to 15 character and number combinations. My code is below which outputs all combinations possible in a line of 36 characters. Also to note, I tried re-sizing the string but it only displayed the first 5 characters and not all of them.

```
class Attack
{
public:

    string combinations;
};

void BruteforceAtt()
{
    Attack bruteforce;

    bruteforce.combinations = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789";

    cout<<"BruteForce Attack is a go..."<<endl;
    cout<<"Searching..."<<endl;
    cout<<""<<endl;

    do
    {
        bruteforce.combinations.resize(5);
        cout<<bruteforce.combinations<<endl;

    } while (next_permutation(bruteforce.combinations.begin(), bruteforce.combinations.end()));

    system("Pause");
};
```

Comment: Not sure what you think [`resize()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/resize/) do, but it does precisely that: change the string to be of size 5. About your question, it is not clear to me what you expect or what you get instead.

Comment: I expect to get all combinations possible, but as you well know passwords don't go up to 32 characters. My string displays all the characters + numbers with all combinations possible. This is good, but I would like to optimize it down (resize) and still generate all numbers and characters. E.g. I have a string of 10, abcdefghij, which produces all combinations but when I resize it to 5, it only gives combinations for abcde

Comment: Why do you use string permutation for this task? Aren't passwords allowed to have repeated characters?

Answer (score 1):

Following may help you: (C++11) (https://ideone.com/zuwyMZ)

```
template <std::size_t N>
bool increase(std::array<std::size_t, N>& a, std::size_t base)
{
    for (auto rit = a.rbegin(); rit != a.rend(); ++rit) {
        ++*rit;
        if (*rit != base) {
            return true;
        }
        *rit = 0;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resize() isn't what you're looking for here. I think you'd be better served restructuring your program somewhat, perhaps like this:

```
string chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789";
string str = "";
str.append(1, 'a');
for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++)
{
  str.append(1, 'a');
  for (int j = 0; j < 36; j++)
  {
    str.replace(i, 1, (string)(chars.at(j)));
    cout << str << endl;
  }
}
```

For future reference, the reason resize() isn't doing what you expect it to do is that you are changing the initial value of bruteforce.combinations ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789") to solely the first five letters of that string ("abcde"), effectively deleting everything after 'e'. If you really wanted, you could change the part in your original loop to something like `cout << bruteforce.combinations.substr(0, 5) << endl;`, but that would produce a large number of duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually need is [combinations with repetition](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~stephens/203/PDF/6-5.pdf). I found this piece of code https://gist.github.com/rg3/731629 and reworked it a litle and voila:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::copy;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

void combinations_r_recursive(const string &elems, unsigned long req_len,
                vector<unsigned long> &pos, unsigned long depth,
                unsigned long margin)
{
    // Have we selected the number of required elements?
    if (depth >= req_len) {
        for (unsigned long ii = 0; ii < pos.size(); ++ii)
            cout << elems[pos[ii]];
        cout << endl;
        return;
    }

    // Try to select new elements to the right of the last selected one.
    for (unsigned long ii = margin; ii < elems.size(); ++ii) {
        pos[depth] = ii;
        combinations_r_recursive(elems, req_len, pos, depth + 1, ii);
    }
    return;
}

void combinations_r(const string &elems, unsigned long req_len)
{
    assert(req_len > 0 && req_len <= elems.size());
    vector<unsigned long> positions(req_len, 0);
    combinations_r_recursive(elems, req_len, positions, 0, 0);
}

const unsigned long comb_len = 3;

int main()
{
    char elements_str[] = "abcdef";
    string elements(elements_str);
    copy(elements_str, elements_str + elements.length(), elements.begin());

    combinations_r(elements, comb_len);
    return 0;
}
```